# Doubt using update query

Tags: php, mysql

I have particular column unique in my database. So regarding that I am using this particular script with the `name` field to avoid duplicacy. But issue is if sometimes I want to update other field except name field than query is not firing. Please give me proper approach with this. using my particular script if I wish to make changes in some row than I need to make changes in name field also...Chk it out.

```
if($name!="") {
    $sql = "select a_name from t_a_list where a_name = '$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        $msg = "<font color=red>Record Not Saved. Album already Exist!</font>";
    }
} else {
    $msg = "<font color=red>Enter Name of Album!</font>";
}
if($msg=="") {
    //Update Query
}
```

Example.. COnsider example I have name field that includes email ids of the user. Now if user want to update his mail id than this script is successfully executing but if he want to make changes to the other field like his name, contact number, address how does this script need to be modify. If user want to change mail id than it will successfully run and avoid and check for mail id if exist. But not for other field. If he want to make changes to other field than he surely have to change his name field first.

Comment: Not sure what your question is - are you asking about how to write an update query?

Comment: Your question is not clear and direct

Comment: I want to avoid duplicacy in the name for that I am using this script. But if I want to update other field not name field it gives me error. How can I modify this to the required conditions. That I not update other field `not name field` it runs successfully.

Comment: I really hope you're not really using deprecated HTML in production.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fire update query when `$msg` is sent, you should use `($msg != '')` in `if` statement.

Comment: You can use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` on your query to avoid SQL errors.

Answer (score 0):

The **text box name** in `script` and in `html` are different *please correct it*